# JAVA (fx) buttontype import

Tags: java, button, javafx

I created a project on my school laptop where I used this import

```
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
```

But If i open my project on a different laptop I get an error: 
cannot find symbol?

How can I solve this? Is this a update problem?

Comment: Which JDK version are you using on each computer? [`ButtonType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonType.html) (along with `Alert` and `Dialog`) was introduced in JDK 8 update 40 (1.8.0u40).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the [java-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonType.html), you will see that `ButtonType` is present since Java 8(u40)

So you have most likely an too old installation on your new laptop.